# Error in POM.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, opennms

I am trying to build the openNMS in eclipse helios using maven. After importing the source using "import existing maven project" i get the around 10k errors. Also i have some error in pom.xml itself, i thought fixing it could reduce the no of errors. The error in pom.xml is

`maven-resources-plugin prior to 2.4 is not supported by m2e. Use maven-resources-plugin version 2.4 or later.`

Iam referring to http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Eclipse_and_OpenNMS for building the openNMS

Iam using maven available at http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/download/

Answer (score 3):

It would help if you told us which versions of Eclipse & m2eclipse you are using, and which version of OpenNMS you are trying to build.

If all else fails, you should be able to run the Maven build from the command line.  In my experience, command line builds are always more reliable and predictable.

Also make sure that you are using the instructions that match the version of OpenNMS you are trying to build.

---

> I have run the command mvn eclipse:eclipse from cmd line which downloaded the libraries in repository then i tried to import the same source directory into eclipse only to find 10k errors

That's not what I meant.

- Get out of eclipse.
- Get a command prompt.
- Create a new directory somewhere the is not in your eclipse workspace.
- Checkout the source code.
- From the command prompt run "mvn install".

And you haven't answered the questions I asked above.  If you don't *want* to answer, fine ... but don't expect us to be able to help you.

---

> ... and i get the error as Build Failure [INFO] There are test failures.

What has happened is that the unit tests have failed, presumably because something needs to be set up to enable testing.  (Perhaps, the tests are trying to talk to a database?)

There are two solutions:

- Find out what is causing the tests to fail, and fix it.  The surefire reports may give you some clues, and there may be some developer documentation on the test setup.
- Turn off the tests by adding `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` to the `mvn` command line; see [this page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html).

It would also be a good idea to read the Maven documentation if you haven't done so already.

Comment: I have run the command mvn eclipse:eclipse from cmd line which downloaded the libraries in repository then i tried to import the same source directory into eclipse only to find 10k errors

Comment: Thats not what @Stephen C is asking can not you just use a higher version as per error message

Comment: Iam using maven 2.2.1 but i do not know about how to get the higher version of maven resource plugin. Does it mean to install the higher version of maven i.e 3.0.3 and then build again?

Comment: @technocrat - I can't advise you if you don't give me the information I asked for.

Comment: Thanks stephen, iam using 1.8.12 version of open nms.As u suggested i have tried mvn install in command line and i get the error as Build Failure  [INFO] There are test failures.

Please refer to D:\OpenNMS\copy\opennms-1.8.12-1\source\opennms-rrd\opennms-rrd-jrobin\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot combine eclipse:eclipse with the m2eclipse support. You cannot use m2eclipse with a project that uses the old resource plugin.

If you want to use eclipse:eclipse, you must use NOT use the 'maven' import from eclipse. Use just 'import existing project'. If you want to use m2eclipse, don't use eclipse:eclipse.

Comment: Thanks dude. I have build in command line using mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true and the final outcome was build successful. Now how do i import it into eclipse.

Comment: You choose. *either* use Import/Maven/Existing Maven Project or mvn eclipse:eclipse followed by Import/Existing Project.

Comment: yup i did it, and iam getting thousands of errors in eclipse. don't know where to start with and how resolve them

Comment: WHich one did you do? If you use eclipse:eclipse, you have to have read the doc and also used setup-workspace.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with the PDFBox source, with the parent pom for that project. I put this in the pdfbox/pom.xml (just to get it to compile in eclipse at lease, which is the only thing I wanted):

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
      <!-- had a process goal here that i removed because it was not compatible -->
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: I have just had this error. PDFBox broke my existing Eclipse really badly (installed something called Tycho). I had to re-install eclipse. Really this shouldn't be put into a common library distrib