# "maven-resources-plugin prior to 2.4 is not supported by m2e"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I'm having problems with m2e (Maven plugin into Eclipse IDE).

I see the following error:
maven-resources-plugin prior to 2.4 is not supported by m2e. Use maven-resources-plugin version 2.4 or later.

I have no idea how to resolve this error.  I'm pretty sure it is an m2e issue (maybe a setup thing?).

Background:

1. I'm attempting to build Tika v0.9
   http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/tags/0.9/
2. I can build using Maven from command line.
3. I can build using Netbeans v7.0.1.
4. I am running Maven 3.0.3.
5. I am running Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1 (Build id: 20110916-0149)
6. I am running m2e v1.0.100.20110804-1717

Thanks for any help.

Albert

Comment: Can you please paste in the relevant parts of your pom you imported into Eclipse?

Comment: I have this problem! Cant solve it!? Any hints?

Answer (score 7):

In the tika.parent project you can find org.apache.apache.6 as parent:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache</artifactId>
    <version>6</version>
    <relativePath />
  </parent>
```

And in the pom.xml from org.apache apache you can find:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

First simple solution:

add the following into the pom of tika.parent under "build - pluginManagement - plugins" (line 230):

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <configuration>
        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  ...
```

And then ask the tika team to use a newer org.apache apache parent pom.

Comment: Try the following additional steps:
 - Select all Projects and "Right click"->Maven->Update Project Configuration
 - Select all Projects and in Menu -> Project -> Clear ... (all)

Answer (score 1):

How did you import your project into eclipse? (the `mvn eclipse:eclipse` goal, or "import maven project" in Eclipse?)

Maybe this answer is of relevance: [Error in POM.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827836/error-in-pom-xml/6830307#6830307)

Comment: This sorta helped, but left me with other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which worked for me is : 
1) Uninstall all the existing Maven plugins from Ecplise.
2) Then install Maven plugin from this location : http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e
-Rushi